# Internally, how do hashes lookup the key to get the value?

Tags: c#, dictionary, hash

Internally, how do hashes lookup the key to get the value?

Would it be bin sort?

Comment: @Gabe: I guess he means: "Binary sorted"

Comment: I suppose a *binary search* makes sense if he was asking about dictionaries, but hashes kind of imply hashing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Dictionary uses the hashcode to calculate the number of the bucket in which the entry is stored. The number of buckets is chosen to be a prime number and the bucket number for a specific key is calculated as the hash code of the key modulo the number of buckets. Because multiple objects can have the same hash code, and multiple hash codes can land in the same bucket, when a key is found in a bucket it must also be compared for equality to be sure it is the correct key. If an incorrect key is found in the bucket, the `next` member of the wrong entry is used to find the next place to search for the desired key.

The result of this algorithm is that when there are no collisions the correct bucket can be found very quickly - O(1), but in the worst case it can take linear time in the number of entries stored in the dictionary. I'm assuming here that the hash code for an object can be calculated in constant time.

The actual code in the .NET implementation can be seen by downloading the reference implementation source, or by using .NET Reflector:

```
private int FindEntry(TKey key)
{
    if (key == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
    }
    if (this.buckets != null)
    {
        int num = this.comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7fffffff;
        for (int i = this.buckets[num % this.buckets.Length]; i >= 0; i = this.entries[i].next)
        {
            if ((this.entries[i].hashCode == num) && this.comparer.Equals(this.entries[i].key, key))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: And after that, a linked list is searched.  The hashcode is based on the number of buckets, so if the number of collisions is high, the bucket is resized, and hashes are recalculated.  (Right?)

Comment: @John - I would rewrite that to be '... collisions is high, the bucket should be resized and the hashes are recalculated'

Comment: @Blankman - note that in none of the 3 answers you have received is there any mentioned of 'bin search'

Comment: @Blankman - More practically a binary search would be possible in the bucket however it would introduce an ordering requirement on your object type so that the list could be sorted.  Adding additional (unnecessary) restrictions to the type of object you can store is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Why is it using modulus?? num % this.buckets.length    that's confusing me a bit....

Comment: @Blankman: There are two good features of modulus: a) it returns a number between 0 and the number of buckets minus one, i.e. the result will never be out of range, and b) different hashcodes will generally be distributed over the buckets almost uniformly for typical data, even if the hashcodes aren't uniformly distributed over the entire range of an int. This reduces the number of collisions while making it easy to implement GetHashCode.

Comment: @Ron - I don't think a binary search will work on a hash - it could work, but there's no guarantee that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

A hash is just an algorithm run against a key that creates (hopefully) a unique value that points to which bucket to store an item in.  So, when you compute the value to try to retrieve that item, your hope is that the hash will point you to the object that you saved earlier.  If not, there should be a pointer about where to look for the next object that shares this hash value.  When you find your item, it will return. If the end of the chain is reached, then your item cannot be found.

See [Hash Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and [Hash Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) for a fuller definition of hashing.